# Is it possible to hide the title of a block in a region to render it separately from the content?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm styling a custom region for the "Active Forum Topics Block" that's included with Drupal. can I hide certain elements in region--[name].tpl.php like as it is done in node.tpl.php?

This is part of my node.tpl.php:

```
    // We hide the elements now so that we can render them later.
    hide($content['comments']);
    hide($content['links']);
    hide($content['field_image']);
    hide($content['links']['#links']['node-readmore']);
    hide($content['links']['#links']['comment-add']);
    hide($content['field_tags']);
```

I would like to do this if it's possible in region--forum_topics.tpl.php (example name "forum_topics"):

```
    hide($content['???']);
```

I don't know what the proper way is, for region.tpl.php. If this is possible, what can I put between brackets to hide the title of the block? If there is a documentation page I can see for more than just the block title, can you please link it?

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier to do this in the [block.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.tpl.php/7) file (using `$block->region` to determine the region) as you have the title printed out separately from content there.

In your test environment you can also use stuff like these to get a better overview of complex variables (will help you with issues like this):

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>'.var_export($content, TRUE).'</pre>');

function print_r_html ($data) {
  ?><pre><?php print_r($data); ?></pre><?php
}
```

Comment: forgive me for being new to drupal. where would I insert this snippet?

Comment: You can use them directly in your template file. drupal_set_message() may need 2 page loads to show up and is generally better used in functions that do not output anything. The custom print_r_html() function is more suitable for template files.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use hook_block_view_alter to hide the title, you can do something like this

```
function MYMODULE_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter(&$data, $block) {
  if arg(xx) = xx {  // detemine the path is a forum topic path
    $data['subject'] = xxx;   // change subject
    // or you can:
    unset($data['subject']);
  }
}
```

ps: MYMODULE is your module name, MODULE_DELTA is block id. Hope it helps.